# Porn description in Yahoo and Bing search results

Tags: search-engines, meta-description

If you check out the **fifth** link **ABLawyers Online Education Centre** on **Bing**:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=ablawyers&form=QBLH&filt=all&qs=n&sk=&sc=1-9

You will see porn text "Jennifer Carpenter ...."

I also get the same with the **sixth** link when you search for "ABlawyers" in **Yahoo**.

When searched on **Google**, it does not have the same problem.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: This usually means the site was hacked.   You'll need to clean it up.  Google maintains a guide for this situation: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Bing cache of the page](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=ablawyers+jennifer+carpenter&d=4756904050493457&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=58cf8417,7b300d7f) shows that it was keyword-stuffed with porn links in the header and footer when the page was last cached.

You'll just have to wait for Yahoo! and Bing to crawl the page again and realize that the page has changed.

Comment: +1 and assuming that this is a new issue (i.e. you haven't made any changes to your site) you need to consider the possibility that your hosting environment is executing malicious content cloaking scripts, as well.